# MiKTeX dvipng fails to generate font bitmaps (pk files)

Tags: miktex, dvi

I am trying to convert a dvi to a png using the following command:

```
dvipng.exe  -q -truecolor1 -freetype0 -D 100 -o "table.png" "table.dvi"
```

This fails with the following error message:

> This is xxxxxx\dvipng.exe (dvipng) 1.15 Copyright 2002-2015 Jan-Ake
>   Larsson log4cxx: No appender could be found for logger (makex).
>   log4cxx: Please initialize the log4cxx system properly. Trying to make
>   PK font recmupmsc at 440 DPI... Running miktex-makemf.exe... log4cxx:
>   No appender could be found for logger (miktex-makemf). log4cxx: Please
>   initialize the log4cxx system properly.
>
> Sorry, but miktex-makemf did not succeed for the following reason:
>
> The recmupmsc source file could not be found.
>
> You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

The thing is that if I use the freetype option, it works fine. So my understanding is that dvipng/gsftopk fail to create the required pk files used when running dvipng without freetype. What is even more confusing is that if I use yap to open the dvi file, I see that the correct pk fonts are created. So I assume the fonts are installed correctly but somehow miktex/dvipng/gsftopk are looking in the wrong place for the font files. Is there a way to debug/configure where gsftopk is looking for the font source files?

Btw: I am using Miktex 2.9.6100

Comment: I had no problems with a small hello world document, so you will have to show some code that show the fonts you are trying to use. Btw: your miktex is rather old.